# Idea on how to create a C function that takes a character string and returns a character string with date and time

Tags: c, string, function, dynamic, character

I'm pretty much new to C and I would like to write a function where it takes a character string and returns a character string with current date and time in the front. I need it for some logging function but I don't want to print directly to the output stream.

```
#define TIME_FORMAT "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] "

char *logMsg(char *msg) {
  char timeStr[23];
  time_t tms;
  struct tm *localTime;

  tms = time(NULL);
  localTime = localtime(&tms);
  strftime(timeStr, sizeof(timeStr), TIME_FORMAT, localTime);

  int lenMsg = strlen(msg);
  int newLen = sizeof(timeStr) + lenMsg + 1;

  char *newStr;

  newStr = (char *) calloc(newLen,sizeof(char));
  strcat(newStr,timeStr);
  strcat(newStr,msg);
  return newStr;
}
```

I know this is a very bad idea as I allocate a new memory every time I call this function but this is the functionality that I want. I don't want to limit my message to a predefined length.

Just an Idea or a design pattern will be very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One option is to force the caller to allocate the extra memory beforehand.

Comment: I agree with @RichardJ.RossIII - also, do not cast the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Comment: What's the question - what's the problem with the code you have above?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with returning allocated memory as long as you call out the requirement that the caller free it.  As the others have mentioned, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer depends on what you intend to do with the function. From what I can presume, you are using this function to create a log string, which you will use several times in your program. Going with approach you have currently, you code will be littered with confusing  calls to free() after each call to logMsg. Having the caller allocate memory will litter your code with calloc and free.

I recommend that you have the caller worry about memory allocation, which is the way C does normally (see strftime() you used).  Though you mentioned that you don't want limit length of message, I recommend allocating once with a sufficiently large limit and free once at the end, in your calling program. This will avoid too many calls to calloc and free.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this insightful answer. Coming from a higher level language, this concepts are abstracted to what I use (SAP ABAP). That is why I'm not sure how to solve this problem with the approach normally done in C.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually the way to do this is to return by value (if you know the size of the array), return a std::string (and by value), or pass the result as pointer argument and let the caller handle allocation/free of the output buffer.

I recommend something like:

```
std::string logMsg(const char *msg)
std::string logMsg(const std::string& msg)
```